# How to check if all values in a custom type are equal

Tags: haskell

I'm searching for a better way to check if all of the values of a given type are equal.

For example, consider:

```
data Foo = Foo {a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int, d :: Int}

allFooEqual :: Foo -> Bool
allFooEqual foo = (a foo == b foo) && (a foo == c foo) && (a foo == d foo)
```

This works, but it isn't exactly a scaleable solution. Is there a more idiomatic way to perform this type of action that I'm missing?

Comment: This question strikes me as rather peculiar. Why do you want such a thing? Records aren't usually what you want for such an operation. Perhaps you want length-indexed vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative:

```
allFooEqual :: Foo -> Bool
allFooEqual (Foo xa xb xc xd) = all (xa==) [xb,xc,xd]
```

This will compare `xa == xb && xa == xc && xa == xd`.

Another:

```
atMostOne :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
atMostOne xs = and $ zipWith (==) xs (drop 1 xs)

allFooEqual :: Foo -> Bool
allFooEqual (Foo xa xb xc xd) = atMostOne [xa,xb,xc,xd]
```

This will compare `xa == xb && xb == xc && xc == xd`.

Accessing "all the `Int`s in a `Foo`" can be done exploiting the scrap-your-boilerplate framework, or GHC Generics, but it looks overkill unless you really have a lot of fields.

```
allFooEqual :: Foo -> Bool
allFooEqual f = atMostOne [ x 
   | Just x <- gmapQ (mkQ Nothing (Just :: Int -> Maybe Int)) f ]
```

There's so much type level stuff here that I strongly recommend against it unless it is really, really needed.

Comment: Aha pattern matching to extract the values seems like a much better solution to me. Thanks! I'll leave this question open for awhile to see if it attracts any other answers as well since you hit it after ~5 minutes.

Comment: Could you expand on that second part? It seems useful but I've never seen it before.

Comment: You could use `RecordWildCards` as in `allFooEqual (Foo {..}) = all (a==) [b,c,d]`

Comment: @jkeuhlen I added something, but scrap-your-boilerplate can not be summarized easily. If you want to learn it, there should be good tutorials around, but be prepared for a non-trivial journey. I'd do without it, when possible.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm not a big fan of that extension, since it shadows the accessors, and can only be used when you have a single record in scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously overkill, but here is a `GHC.Generics` based solution that lets you automatically generate a typeclass `FieldsMatch` which provides such a function `fieldsMatch :: FieldsMatch a => a -> Bool` that returns true if all the fields of the same type in your record have the same value.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, ExistentialQuantification, DefaultSignatures, 
      FlexibleContexts #-}
module FieldsMatch (FieldsMatch(..)) where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Typeable

-- `Some` is an existential type that we need to store each field
data Some = forall a. (Eq a, Typeable a) => Some a

-- This is the class we will be deriving
class FieldsMatch a where
  -- in general, this is the type of `fieldsMatch`...
  fieldsMatch :: a -> Bool

  -- ... except the default implementation has slightly different constraints.
  default fieldsMatch :: (Generic a, GetFields (Rep a)) => a -> Bool
  fieldsMatch = noneDiffering . getFields . from
    where
      noneDiffering :: [Some] -> Bool
      noneDiffering [] = True
      noneDiffering (x:xs) = all (notDiffering x) xs && noneDiffering xs

      notDiffering :: Some -> Some -> Bool
      Some x `notDiffering` Some y = case cast y of
        Nothing -> True
        Just z -> x == z

class GetFields f where
  -- | This function takes the generic representation of a datatype and
  -- recursively traverses it to collect all its fields. These need to
  -- have types satisfying `Eq` and `Typeable`.
  getFields :: f a -> [Some]

instance (GetFields a, GetFields b) => GetFields (a :*: b) where
  getFields (l :*: r) = getFields l ++ getFields r

instance (GetFields a, GetFields b) => GetFields (a :+: b) where
  getFields (L1 l) = getFields l
  getFields (R1 r) = getFields r

instance GetFields U1 where
  getFields U1 = []

instance (Typeable a, Eq a) => GetFields (K1 i a) where
  getFields (K1 x) = [Some x]

instance GetFields a => GetFields (M1 i t a) where
  getFields (M1 x) = getFields x

  default fieldsMatch :: (Generic a, GetFields (Rep a)) => a -> Bool
  fieldsMatch = noneDiffering . getFields . from
    where
      noneDiffering :: [Some] -> Bool
      noneDiffering [] = True
      noneDiffering (x:xs) = all (notDiffering x) xs || noneDiffering xs

      notDiffering :: Some -> Some -> Bool
      Some x `notDiffering` Some y = case cast y of
        Nothing -> True
    Just z -> x == z
```

You can try this out in GHCi:

```
ghci> :set -XDeriveGeneric
ghci> data Foo b = Foo Int Int b Bool deriving (Generic)
ghci> instance (Eq b, Typeable b) => FieldsMatch (Foo b)
ghci> Foo 1 1 True True -- fields of the same type are equal
True
ghci> Foo 1 2 True (1,2) -- 1 /= 2 even though they are the same type
False
```